# cannot denodeify methods in node-ftp module

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am new to both node.js and promise style function call. By looking at an denodeify example at http://runnable.com/Ulatc0QnzUgUAAAK/adapting-node-js-with-q-for-promises, I am trying to denodeify the methods of the node.js node-ftp module as following:

```
var ftp = require('ftp');
var q = require('q');
var ftpClient = new ftp();
ftpClient.on('ready', function() {
    var ftpList = q.denodeify(ftpClient.list);
    ftpList().then(function(list) {
        console.log(list);
    }.then(null, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }).done(function() {
        ftpClient.end();
    });
});
ftpClient.connect();
```

However, when running that code with node, it shows the error "list error: TypeError: Object # has no method '_pasv'"

I am not sure what's wrong with that piece of code. Does anyone know what's wrong with that? Can you point me some way to debug/troubleshoot the cause of that error message?

Thanks.

Comment: You're also missing a closing paren at the end of your first `.then()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you pass

```
ftpClient.list
```

to `Q.denodefiy`, you are getting the function object, `list` from the `ftpClient` object. It will be just a function and the relationship with the parent is lost. This is important because, the bound function `list` might be dependent on the `ftpClient` object. So, you must make sure that link is not broken.

Quoting from the [`Q.denodeify` docs](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qdenodeifynodefunc-args),

> Note that if you have a ***method*** that uses the Node.js callback pattern,
>   as opposed to just a function, you will need to bind its this value
>   before passing it to denodeify, like so:
>
> ```
> var Kitty = mongoose.model("Kitty");
> var findKitties = Q.denodeify(Kitty.find.bind(Kitty));
> ```
>
> The better strategy for methods would be to use `Q.nbind`, as shown below.

So, you can fix your code in two ways,

1. Using `Q.denodeify` and [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), like this

   ```
   var ftpList = q.denodeify(ftpClient.list.bind(ftpClient));
   ```
2. Using [`Q.nbind`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qnbindnodemethod-thisarg-args), like this

   ```
   var ftpList = q.nbind(ftpClient.list, ftpClient);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `q.nbind`

```
q.nbind(ftpClient.list, ftpClient);
```