# How to turn callback function with Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm using Bluebird promises and trying to get below function with Promisify working:

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

function _test_encode() {
    var cert = fs.readFileSync('public.pub'); 
    return jwt.verify(token, cert, function(err, decoded) {
        console.log(decoded);
    });
}
```

I tried below:

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var jwtVerifyAsync = Promise.promisify(jwt.verify);

function _test_encode() {
    var cert = fs.readFileSync('public.pub');  // get public key
    return jwtVerifyAsync(token, cert).then(function(decoded) {
        console.log(decoded);
    });
}
```

But I'm getting:

```
Possibly unhandled TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'decode'
```

Is there something I'm missing here that I need to get it working?
I just want to get _test_encode function to return result of the promise and use it in my other functions.

Verify function is below:

```
module.exports.verify = function(jwtString, secretOrPublicKey, options, callback) {
  if ((typeof options === 'function') && !callback) {
    callback = options;
    options = {};
  }

  if (!options) options = {};

  var done;

  if (callback) {
    done = function() {
      var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
      return process.nextTick(function() {
        callback.apply(null, args);
      });
    };
  } else {
    done = function(err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      return data;
    };
  }

  if (!jwtString){
    return done(new JsonWebTokenError('jwt must be provided'));
  }

  var parts = jwtString.split('.');

  if (parts.length !== 3){
    return done(new JsonWebTokenError('jwt malformed'));
  }

  if (parts[2].trim() === '' && secretOrPublicKey){
    return done(new JsonWebTokenError('jwt signature is required'));
  }

  var valid;

  try {
    valid = jws.verify(jwtString, secretOrPublicKey);
  } catch (e) {
    return done(e);
  }

  if (!valid)
    return done(new JsonWebTokenError('invalid signature'));

  var payload;

  try {
   payload = this.decode(jwtString);
  } catch(err) {
    return done(err);
  }

  if (typeof payload.exp !== 'undefined') {
    if (typeof payload.exp !== 'number') {
      return done(new JsonWebTokenError('invalid exp value'));
    }
    if (Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) >= payload.exp)
      return done(new TokenExpiredError('jwt expired', new Date(payload.exp * 1000)));
  }

  if (options.audience) {
    var audiences = Array.isArray(options.audience)? options.audience : [options.audience];
    var target = Array.isArray(payload.aud) ? payload.aud : [payload.aud];

    var match = target.some(function(aud) { return audiences.indexOf(aud) != -1; });

    if (!match)
      return done(new JsonWebTokenError('jwt audience invalid. expected: ' + payload.aud));
  }

  if (options.issuer) {
    if (payload.iss !== options.issuer)
      return done(new JsonWebTokenError('jwt issuer invalid. expected: ' + payload.iss));
  }

  return done(null, payload);
};
```

Comment: It sounds like `jwt.verify` doesn't receive the right arguments. It throws an exception which you don't catch.

Comment: @FelixKling I've just updated with `jwt.verify` functioin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot denodeify methods](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22419382/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trying to call `this.decode`, but you've stripped away the context by promisifying it, so `this` isn't `jwt` like it expects.  You can keep context through promisification by passing it as a second argument:

```
var jwtVerifyAsync = Promise.promisify(jwt.verify, jwt);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an older post, but for anyone reading this now, be aware of which version of Bluebird you are using.

As of v3.0, the second argument passed into the *promisify* method is an *options* object. See [here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/new-in-bluebird-3.html).

This code should now be:

```
var jwtVerifyAsync = Promise.promisify(jwt.verify, {context: jwt})
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used `jwt.verify(token, secret)` without `promisify`. It worked just fine. I suppose with latest version of JWT you don't need to `promisify`.

Comment: That's because it has fallen back to the synchronous version of the `verify` function. This is somehow an ongoing debate. https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/111